# Getting stuck on trying to add changestream to my backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, changestream

I am building a chatroom app with Node, express, MongoDB, React and SocketIO and i am trying to implement changestreams to get the chats from other people to update the frontend. But from reading the docs and watching what i could find on youtube i seem to get stuck with a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') ".

This is just a piece from the the backend so you dont have to read the whole thing, just know that everything else works as intended.

```
const changeStream = db.collection('rooms').watch();
changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
    console.log(change);
    io.emit('messageResponse', change);
});
```

So what i am expecting from this is when any change happens to my "rooms" collection, it will emit that to my frontend.
But all i get is that the collection is undefined. I've tried putting it in an async func with the same result. Can anyone that has does similar work tell me what maybe wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i fixed it! I put the changestream inside the socket connection and then tweaked the socket emit abit. Now works as intended :D

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
const changeStream = db.collection('rooms').watch();
changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
    console.log(Object.values(change.updateDescription.updatedFields)[0]);
    io.emit('messageResponse', Object.values(change.updateDescription.updatedFields)[0]);
});
socket.on('message', (data) => {
    io.emit('messageResponse', data);
});
```

});